# In Android Studio, how can I quickly run the same app on two devices?

Tags: android-studio

I am working on a project that uses WiFi Direct. Naturally it takes at two or more devices to test this effectively. For part of the development, the apps will only work if both devices have my latest code changes installed.

Both devices are physically connected to the USB ports on the development machine.

Right now, if I Run the project, it will ask me which device to use. I can wait for run to finish and select Run project again.

For the subsequent Runs, Android Studio does not ask if I want to switch devices, because it has an existing connection with the first device. This is indicated by the red Stop button becoming active.

[image]

So far, I've found two ways to break the connection with the first device, thereby allowing me to run the project on the second device.

- I can use the Stop App button. Then I do have to re-run the app from the Home Screen on the first device. (slightly inconvenient) Unfortunately, if I've been using Instant Run to hot-swap code changes, sometimes launching from the home screen activates and old version of the app. I have to use Clean And Re-Run to overcome this which adds to the time needed.
- I can reach over (slightly inconvenient) and disconnect the first device physically from the USB port. The app continues to run on the first device which is nice. I can re-attach the USB plug almost immediately

After either of these I can run the app on the second device.

[image]

Is there a quicker way?

- I'd be interested in being able to disconnect without stopping the app or physically unplugging the device.
- Ideally I would like to be able to run the app on both devices at once, but I'm not sure this is possible. If it is possible, it would save time not having to wait for one Run to finish before launching the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised I didn't think of this earlier.

One can use the Shift or Ctrl key to select both devices to run.

[image]

- Instant Run features are not active when deploying to multiple devices.
- The run is sequential. The first device finishes, then the second one automatically starts.
- Switching from a One Device run back to a Two Device run is still a bit inconvenient, so:

  > I'd be interested in being able to disconnect without stopping the app or physically unplugging the device.